# Using python how do I get AWS parameter store secret data using assume role

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Currently I am able to get my secret params from AWS parameter store using this code

```
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='qa')
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    accessKey = credentials.access_key
    secretKey = credentials.secret_key
    print("accessKey= " + str(accessKey) + " secretKey="+ secretKey)

    store = EC2ParameterStore(
        aws_access_key_id=accessKey,
        aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,
        #aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,  # optional
        region_name=awsRegion
    )
    try:
        secretParams = store.get_parameter(mysessionPath, decrypt=True)
    except:
        print("Could not find parameter")

    secretParams = str(secretParams[roleSessionName]).replace("\n","")
    secretParamsDict = eval(secretParams)
    self.secretA = secretParamsDict["secretA"]
```

Because I need to run this code in CI Jenkins which is also in AWS I need to use assumeRole method. How can I achieve the results using Assume Role given I have: roleARN and roleSessionName

Comment: Is this information not documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) service:

1. Call sts [assume_role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) providing it with your role to be assumed. 
   This will return temporary  'AccessKeyId', 'SecretAccessKey' and 'SessionToken'.
2. Use the temporary credentials to create new boto3 [Session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) which you will use to call all the APIs you are allowed to.

One thing to remember is that assuming role is not cumulative, i.e. you will use your current permissions for the boto3 session. Thus you will be able to do only what the role allows you to do in the boto3 session.

Comment: I tried -->         client = boto3.client('sts')
        response = client.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::1234:role/myRole' RoleSessionName=RoleSessionName)  I get botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Comment: @user3556956 You need permissions in the first place to use `sts`. Once you have permissions to use the service, the you can start assuming the roles through it.

Comment: I have permissions. I am able to log in manually to AWS I also have credentials under --> C:\Users\[myUsername]\.aws   it looks like --> [ABC] aws_access_key_id = xyz aws_secret_access_key = 123434

Comment: @user3556956 The `qa` profile which you use can use the `sts`? If yes, than the `qa` boto3 session can be used to create `sts` session.

Comment: Can you pls give me a sample code how? I tried this but get error --> client = boto3.client('sts') response = client.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::1234:role/myRole' RoleSessionName=RoleSessionName) I get botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials